# Using "provided" with sbt breaks Intellij syntax highlighting for Spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

My dependencies are below.  I've been told by the Spark people that I'm supposed to add `% "provided"` after the spark dependencies so they don't get bundled with my jar (not that I agree, but anyway). Now if I do add "provided" the syntax highlighting for the Spark modules breaks :( Everything is highlighted in red (unresolved) (after I do a `sbt gen-idea`).  It continues to build OK.

Has anyone found a solution? I'm worried that I might have to hack together a script that adds the "provided" words just before I compile and then removes them after the build.

Making Spark, SBT and Intellij all play together is like playing wack-a-mole, it seems if you wack one problem, another just sprouts up!

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.10.1" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.14" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.5" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.2" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  "io.spray" %%  "spray-json" % "1.3.1" withSources() withJavadoc(),
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.0.0-cdh5.1.3") withSources() withJavadoc(),
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.0-cdh5.1.3") withSources() withJavadoc()
)
```

With provided:

```
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.0.0-cdh5.1.3" % "provided") withSources() withJavadoc(),
  ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.0-cdh5.1.3" % "provided") withSources() withJavadoc()
```